# What is the intuition (geometrical interpretation) of $[\omega\wedge\omega]$ in Cartan's structure equation?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, connections, principal-bundles, cartan-geometry

The Cartan's equation in principal bundle:

$$
{\textrm{hor d}}\omega = \textrm{d}\omega + \frac{1}{2}[\omega\wedge\omega]
$$

Is there an intuition or geometric interpretation of the second term, $[\omega\wedge\omega]$?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1235409/305862)

Comment: and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/440816/305862)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the links. I've read them but they don't address my question. I was asking how to understand $[\omega\wedge\omega]$ geometrically, not the bracket of two vectors, or $\textrm{d}\omega$.

Comment: I think it can be difficult to find geometric intuition for every formula and equation in differential geometry. Geometric intuition might be a starting point, but often leads to algebraic structures that facilitate the calculations needed to uncover new geometric insights. I think differential forms are a good example. It is easier to have geometric intuition for formulas involving tangent vectors. But it is much harder to find *useful* geometric intuition for covectors in the cotangent space. Their power algebraic properties of vectors fields are expressed better in terms of 1-forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a direct geometrically intuitive way to see this. However, one way to get to this is formula is to look for a way to make $d\omega$ a horizontal $2$-form that is tensorial with respect to the action of $G$.

Let $P$ be a principal $G$-bundle over $M$. For convenience, I will assume that the Lie group $G$ is a matrix group. Recall that $\omega$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $1$-form on the principal bundle $P$ such that given any section $s$ of the principal bundle $P$,
$$
\nabla s = s^*\omega.
$$
Given any section $\bar{s}$, there is a map $g: M \rightarrow G$ such that $\bar{s} = sg$. A straightforward calculation shows that
$$
\bar{s}^*\omega = g^{-1}s^*\omega g + g^{-1}\,dg.
$$
Clearly, $d\bar\omega$ depends on both $d\omega$ and $dg$. To get a geometric invariant, we want to find something that depends on $g$ but not on $dg$. A hint is given by the fact that the second term on the right satisfies the Maurer-Cartan equations
$$
d\Omega + \Omega\wedge \Omega = 0.
$$
On the other hand, the first term is defined using the adjoint action of $G$ on $\omega$. The vertical derivative will be the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{g}$. An explicit calculation shows that
$$
d\bar\omega = g^{-1}d\omega\,g -\Omega\wedge \omega - \omega\wedge\Omega - \Omega\wedge \Omega.
$$
At this point, it is not hard to see that "completing the square" eliminates the last 3 terms on the right:
$$
d\bar\omega + \bar\omega\wedge\bar\omega = g^{-1}(d\omega + \omega\wedge\omega)
$$
This means that the action of $G$ on the $2$-form
$$
d\omega + \omega\wedge\omega
$$
is zero-th order, i.e., it does not depend on the derivatives of $g \in G$. This implies the $2$-form is a well-defined tensor on $P$ and therefore a geometric invariant.

Comment: Your fist equation, is there an extra $s$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

As the notation you use suggests, $d\omega+\tfrac12[\omega\wedge\omega]$ is the horizontal projection of $d\omega$, so $\tau:=-\tfrac12[\omega\wedge\omega]$ is the vertical projection of $d\omega$. This means that it vanishes upon insertion of one vector field that is horizontal and coincides with $d\omega$ on vertical vector fields. By definition, for vector fields $\xi$ and $\eta$, one has $\tau(\xi,\eta)=[\omega(\xi),\omega(\eta)]$, which readily shows that it vanishes if either $\xi$ or $\eta$ is horizontal. To check that it coincides with $d\omega$ on vertical vector fields, it suffices to insert a fundamental vector field. So for $A\in\mathfrak g$ consider the fundamental vector field $\zeta_A$, which by definition has the property that $\omega(\zeta_A)=A$. But the infinitesimal version of equivariancy of $\omega$ under the principal right action reads as $\mathcal L_{\zeta_A}\omega=-\text{ad}_A\circ\omega$ where $\mathcal L$ is the Lie derivative. Since $d(\omega(\zeta_A))=0$,  $\mathcal L_{\zeta_A}\omega=i_{\zeta_A}d\omega$. But this exactly says that $d\omega(\zeta_A,\eta)=-(\text{ad}_A\circ \omega)(\eta)=-[A,\omega(\eta)]=-[\omega(\zeta_A),\omega(\eta)]$. Hence indeed $\tau$ coincides with $d\omega$ on vertical vector fields.

Comment: Was difficult for me to understand your answer, till I went through the proof of the Cartan's structure equation. Now it makes much more sense. Thank you!